# Access a service in console application with service requies a certificate

Tags: c#, ssl

I am trying to read the data from below service request url.When I open this in my Browser I could see the data .But  when I want to do the same using ConsoleApplication it didn't work.

https://wb01.miracast.com/Primary/services/requestlist/getrequestlist?id=80FC46F4&queryby=requestid&format=xml

One thing I noticed was it asks me to select the certificate and when I select the certificate(in this case it is  sr.dns.miracast.com(IT Machine Auth CA 2) ), it returns the data and displays it in browser. I have this certificate installed in the Personal, TrustedRootAuthority in my Desktop from I my code is also running in Visual Studio.

Now how do I achieve the same using c# console application code. I mean how do I specify the certificate to the code ?

I tried the below but it throws the Not found error in reposne catch block.

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        // retrieve an avatar image from the Web
        string avatarUri = "https://wb01.miracast.com/Primary/services/requestlist/getrequestlist?id=80FC46F4&queryby=requestid&format=xml";
        HttpWebRequest request =
            (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(avatarUri);
        request.BeginGetResponse(GetAvatarImageCallback, request);
    }

    private void GetAvatarImageCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request != null)
        {
            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
                //avatarImg = Texture2D.FromStream(
                //    graphics.GraphicsDevice,
                //    response.GetResponseStream());
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
               // gamerTag = "Gamertag not found.";
                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After attaching the same certificate through code it worked.

```
        string avatarUri = "https://wb01.miracast.com/Primary/services/requestlist/getrequestlist?id=80FC46F4&queryby=requestid&format=xml";
        HttpWebRequest request =
            (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(avatarUri);

        request.Method = "GET";        // Post method


        X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(@"C:\Users\kim\Desktop\oas-test.cer");
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        // Attaching the Certificate To the request

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy =
                               new TrustAllCertificatePolicy();

        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse wResp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        StreamReader loResponseStream = new
          StreamReader(wResp.GetResponseStream(), enc);

        string Response = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

        loResponseStream.Close();
        wResp.Close();
```